# Get name of the class which uses QuerysetAPI

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am using Django 1.4 on Mac.
I have following calls in my code -

`Entry.objects.filter()`
`Entry.objects.all()`

And in different `Class CallStackManager`, I am overriding these *querysetAPI* calls by using `get_query_set()` as follows-

```
def get_query_set(self):
        """
        gets call stack 
        """
        log.info(traceback.format_stack())
        return super(CallStackManager, self).get_query_set()
```

How can I get name of the (here it is `Model Class Entry`) calling `filter()` in `Class CallStackManager` `get_query_set()` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs on [custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers), you can access the model class with `self.model`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I skipped such a obvious thing!